# Correct mysql query to query one table and have that provide information for another table query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 separate tables, both of which I need to query simultaneously to get the correct information to display. The tables are members and posts. Through an html form, a user enters criteria for the members table, and then I need to use the primary index of all those specific members to find all the posts submitted by those members and then do a sort on the posts table results. The results will be a mixture of rows from the two tables. Both tables have a primary index of the name 'id'. So far what I've come up with is:

```
$sql_get_posts = mysqli_query($link, "(SELECT id, username FROM members WHERE active='y' AND gender='M' AND city='Yuma' AND state='Arizona') UNION (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE member_id='id' AND active='y' ORDER BY list_weight DESC)") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

The error I'm getting is "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns".

I need to then cycle through the returned results from both tables to populate the content seen by the user:

```
<?php
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_get_posts)) {
     $post_id = $row['id']; //This should be the post primary index named 'id', not the member primary index also name 'id'
     $member_id = $row['member_id']; //This is the member_id row in the post table referencing this particular member who wrote this post 
     $member_username = $row['username']; //This is a row stored in the member table
     $title = $row['title']; //This is a row stored in post table
     ******//and on and on getting rows from only the post table
   }
```

Edit My SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `age` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `gender` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `active` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
 `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `comments` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
  `post_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `list_weight` double NOT NULL,
  `active` enum('y','n') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=47 ;
```

Comment: Show the tables structure of both tables.

Comment: Union work only when you have same number of column in bot select clause.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ It's in phpmyadmin. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: the problem is number of columns in both query. in your first query only two field are selected,next query all the field are selected that's issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) instead of union, union assumes the tables you're combining are similar, whereas join merges the columns of two tables.

Something like:

```
SELECT members.id, members.username, posts.*
FROM members
INNER JOIN posts
ON members.id = posts.member_id
WHERE members.active='y' AND members.gender='M' AND members.city='Yuma' AND members.state='Arizona'
ORDER BY posts.list_weight DESC
```

Comment: where are the conditions?

Comment: updated to add back the where clause, order by, and specific column names.

Comment: @Solaris. This seems to work. I'm curious though, how does php/mysql know that I'm asking for the post table primary index in the line: $post_id = $row['id'];, and not the members table primary index of the same name?

Comment: I assume it's because the posts id overwrites the member id due to it being added second. To ensure no overlap of names you can change `SELECT members.id,...` to `SELECT members.id as MemberID,` or something similar.

Comment: I just changed $post_id = $row['id']; to $post_id = $row['posts.id']; and it still works! Mind Blown. I really need to crack open an sql book to examine all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

But you have selected only 2 columns in first query and "*" for second select query

Comment: Kind of realizing that now after all the responses. People say I should use JOIN instead.

Answer (score 0):

use joins

```
SELECT m.id, m.username,p.* FROM members m JOIN posts p on m.active='y' AND m.gender='M' AND m.city='Yuma' AND m.state='Arizona' and p.member_id='id' AND p.active='y' ORDER BY p.list_weight DESC
```

or you can use

```
SELECT m.id, m.username,p.* FROM members m,posts p where m.active='y' AND m.gender='M' AND m.city='Yuma' AND m.state='Arizona' and p.member_id='id' AND p.active='y' ORDER BY p.list_weight DESC
```

Comment: I'm not a Mysql Ninja. Where is m coming from?

Comment: m is a object of table members,as you can see in the query `members m` and `posts p` so we can access the columns simply using these objects like m.id,p.name so on